# Batch/CMD how to not show "No Disk" error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In batch file I am trying to do something like the below:

```
copy %0 D:\
```

But this will give me the error "No Disk". So
I tried:

```
if exist D: (copy %0 D:\)
```

But that gave me the same error, how do I get around this?

EDIT:This is with no disk in, but I want the copy command to be run if the batch file is opened and there is a disk there. But if there is no disk then not to display an error.

Answer (score 0):

It needs the trailing backslash when checking paths - but the operating system you are using makes a difference too.

```
if exist "D:\" copy "%~0" D:\
```

Comment: @Neb9  Did you see my comment about the OS?

Answer (score 0):

redirect the output to nirwana (you can still execute code dependend on failure or success, if you need to):

```
copy %0 d: >nul  && (
  echo success.
  goto :CopyOK
) || (
  echo failed.
  goto :NoDisk
)  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The windows cmd `wmic cdrom get MediaLoaded` has output

```
MediaLoaded  
FALSE  
[possible blank lines]
```

when there is no disk in the drive, or if there is a disk, but it is not formatted (pretty much anything where you can't write to it (the value TRUE means you can write to it.)

This batch file looks for TRUE on the second line and then you can put your command there. The goto is needed to skip the blank lines.
For this example I just echo out TRUE

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic cdrom get MediaLoaded') do (
    if %%a == TRUE (
        @echo %%a
    )
    goto :NEXT
)
:NEXT
```